# Is there a way to record my iPad screen for free?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, software-recommendation, video

Good afternoon,

I own an iPad 2 and a Macbook Pro. I am looking for a free solution to recording my iPad's screen from my computer. I plan to record the gameplay of various iOS games and upload them on video sharing websites.

About my iPad 2 - 
Version: 6.0.1

Not jailbroken.

I apologize if this exact question has already been answered but I have been unable to find an answer that is suitable for my specific needs. Finding a free alternative to Reflector seems to be very difficult!

All answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is jailbreaking an option?

Comment: Use Photo Booth. (This is a joke, by the way. It would work though...)

Comment: I would prefer not to have to resort to jailbreaking my device. I understand that I could use the camera on the computer to record the iPad's screen but I obviously do not want to do that.

Comment: Thank you, Arne and daviewales.
<br>
It seems that, at this point, Reflector is my best option. I hope they do develop more free screen recorders for iOS devices in the future. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.
<br>
Also, I would like to thank whoever turned my "Answer" into a comment.

Comment: you should have the ability to comment on your own question, even with only 1 rep.

Answer (score 4):

There used to be some free apps, but they stopped working because the devs didn't have time to update them to work with the latest changes to airplay.

If you are willing to pay a bit of money you can get apps which turn your Mac into an Airplay server. You can then mirror your iPad's screen to your Mac, and record it there.

- [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) is $12.99
- [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com) is $14.99
- [X-Mirage](http://www.x-mirage.com/x-mirage/) is $16.00

Check them out, and work out which one is best for you.

**EDIT:**

X-Mirage has a 7-day free trial, so I think it's the closest you'll get to a "free" solution.

Answer (score 4):

To record your iPad's screen, you could use QuickTime X that comes for free with OS X Yosemite and OS X El Capitan.

**Unfortunately your iPad must be running iOS 8 or later for this to work.**

- Connect your iPad to your computer (with the 30 pin or Lightning connector)
- Open QuickTime Player, usually found in the "Utilities" folder of the Applications folder
- Click File > New Movie Recording
- From beside the red "record" button click the source arrow [image]
- Choose your device and click record!

(Image from [ioshacker.com](http://ioshacker.com/how-to/use-quicktime-record-screen-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-running-ios-8))

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a free option. There are products like [X-Mirage](http://www.x-mirage.com/x-mirage/) (USD 16), which lets you record your device via AirPlay. This is probably the most hassle-free and cheap solution.

You can also buy an HDMI adapter [from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A/apple-digital-av-adapter), or some third party version, and record your gameplay that way using e.g. an HDD-recorder with HDMI input. For this solution you obviously need quite a bit of hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Wait a few more weeks until OS X Yosemite is released. 
In Yosemite it's possible to record your iOS screen with QuickTime when you've connected your device with an USB cable..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just get a different type of device flip the camera and record while the other device is playing games?

Answer (score 0):

Although this solution is not technically free, it is a long term solution. You can buy an adapter to stream live whatever is on your iPad screen to your Mac screen. Then using a PC screen recorder system to record the "livestream" footage. There is free screen recording software out there. Software such as CamStudio and TinyTake offer pretty decent recording options for free, and extra if you pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

Get  airshou. Here's the link cherryroad.xyz/airshou. To use it just click record, choose your orientation and quality, hit next and swipe up from the bottom of your screen. Then click AirPlay and press AirShou. Wait a few seconds, and the recording starts

Answer (score -1):

Just use another mobile to record ur iOS screen as I also have same problem

Comment: This actually is a pragmatic solution for casual documentation needs. It doesn't make sense to pay for professional tools on a budget that prioritizes free. +1 in my book

Answer (score -3):

Just go to camera and click the buttion flip camera! If this doesnt work I dont know what will because seriously I dont have an iPad and I have no clue om how to use it

Answer (score -3):

Download irec
It will help you record and it is quick free and easy xx :3

Comment: Just so all are aware, iRec is no longer an option, it is listed under the "does not work" category in the emu4ios.net store.

Answer (score -4):

emu4ios.com...install then find iRec and click install and begin